# how to determine whether the input is backspace

Tags: linux, shell

see the following code

```
stty cbreak -echo  
input==`dd if=/dev/tty bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null`  
stty -cbreak echo  
if [ "$input" = "a" ];then
    echo "the input is a"
fi
```

how I can determine whether the input is backspace under shell. In other words,what is the symbol of backspace.

Comment: Try this: in vi, where you 'a' in quotes, in insert mode, press ctrl-v and then backspace. Basically it's ascii 8.

Comment: but I want to check it under shell，not in vi

Comment: @yaxin: You asked what the symbol for backspace was. NitzanShaked gave you a method for finding that out.

Comment: But you edit the script in vi...

Comment: @NitzanShaked sorry,I misunderstood what you say.Yes,it works.thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you lack the ability to insert a literal backspace character into your editor, you can use `echo -ne '\b'` instead. This tells echo to suppress emitting a newline, and to interpret some backslash escape sequences as special characters. `\b` is backspace:

```
if [ "$input" = $(echo -ne '\b') ];then
```

When I use `vi`, I can use the keystrokes `^V^H` to get a backspace character into the script. In `emacs`, it would be `C-q C-h`.

```
if [ "$input" = "^H" ];then
```